# After converting application to ARC, main method shows memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have converted my application to ARC. While seeking memory leaks using instruments main.m shows a huge memory leak at following :

```
@autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
        return retVal;
    }
```

How can i resolve this memory leak.

Comment: enable NSZoomibee and check it

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the 4th parameter, which is the application delegate class name, maybe that a reason.